# Show community wiki answers on profile page

Tags: support, profile-page, community-wiki

My profile page doesn't show community wiki answers in the answers section. For example, if I sort by upvotes, [this question with 10 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about/3023454#3023454), which hasn't been edited by anyone else, should appear on the first page, but it doesn't.

There might be some reasoning behind why it's not shown, but it's less confusing to include it than to exclude it from the list of answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's there, it's just collapsed into a single link with your three other answers on that question (10 + 1 + 1 + 0 up votes):

[image: Collapsed answer link]

It might be nice if you were able to expand that to get links to the individual posts though, as it seems it currently just goes to the most recent.

Comment: D'Oh! The reason I missed it was that I was [specifically looking for answers with 10 upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93063/notification-of-nice-answer-pointing-to-the-wrong-post).